# Limit accessible scope (@Autowire/@Resource) of a Spring Bean to a package

Tags: spring

How do you limit the accessible scope of a spring bean?

Is this even possible, or recommended?

I ask, as I have a case where I would like a `ConnectionManager` class to <strike>`@Autowired`</strike> `@Resource` each of its specific `IExternalConnection`s (in case I later need separate `ConnectionManager` classes).

However, I don't want other classes using those connections directly. It would make sense to me to have some way of making the `IExternalConnection` beans package private.

Most questions about Spring Bean scope relate to the lifetime of the `Bean`, which is specifically ***not*** what this question is about

**Edit:**
Here's some code snippets to clarify what I mean

```
public class ConnectionFactory {
    @Resource(name = "defaultConnectionManager")
    private IExternalConnectionManager              defaultConnectionManager;

    @Resource(name = "someOtherConnectionManager")
    private IExternalConnectionManager              someOtherConnectionManager;
}
```

The configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class Connections {
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory defaultConnectionFactory() {
        return new ConnectionFactory();
    }
    @Bean
    public IExternalConnectionManager defaultConnectionManager() {
        return new defaultConnectionManager();
    }
    @Bean
    public IExternalConnectionManager someOtherConnectionManager() {
        return new someOtherConnectionManager();
    }
}
```

The goal being making `Connections` only provide the `defaultConnectionFactory` Bean, and not `defaultConnectionManager` or `someOtherConnectionManager`

Comment: Show the relevant code

Comment: And what prevents you from making them package private?

Comment: Make the configuration method package private, and that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you ?
Define the second bean with in the scope of first bean

```
    <bean class="connectionFactory" >
    <property name="defaultConnectionManager">
        <bean class="com.xyz.Connectionmanager" >
            <property name="connection">
                <bean class="com.xyz.Connection" ></bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: hmm, the main issue is if a new `ConnectionFactory` class needed to access the  `Connections`, would it get the same instances of `IExternalConnectionManager`?

Comment: I don't think so. But why would you need multiple connection factories using the same connection manager ?

Comment: mostly for how it handles missing or invalid connections. One would be for Production, another would be for Development/Debug. I could make it lookup a resource file, but I would prefer making them separate classes.

Comment: regardless, knowing how to limit the scope of a `Bean` seems like it would be a good thing, as not all Beans should be accessible by all code. The spirit of the question is more about the general case, rather than my specific problem.

Comment: I think spring does not provide that because that is what java access modifiers do. Let's say even if spring provided this feature, if the ConnectionManager is public and it's methods are publicly accessible, any external code could access it. I think for your situation java access modifiers should do it.